# Hyperledge Composer publish definitions failed

Tags: hyperledger-composer

This is not a duplicates, at least I have the right version of Composer, I have also read the 3 stackflow composer questions.

I tried to publish definition, the Basic-Sample-Network package came from the git respository, the Basic-sample-network.bna archive file, here's the command :

composer network deploy -p hlfv1.json -a basic-sample-network.bna -i admin -s adminpw

### The error (seems to be a generic error message):

```
Identifier: basic-sample-network@0.1.3
Description: The Hello World of Hyperledger Composer samples
```

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: event message must be properly signed by an identity from the same organization as the peer: [failed deserializing event creator: [Expected MSP ID Org1MSP, received ]]

```
at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:189:19)
at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:169:8)
```

### at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:634:14

Here're my environments :

composer -v :

composer-cli                   v0.10.0

composer-admin                 v0.10.0

composer-client                v0.10.0

composer-common                v0.10.0

composer-runtime-hlf           v0.10.0

composer-runtime-hlfv1         v0.10.0

npm c 3.10.10

hlfv1.json profile :

{
    "type": "hlfv1",
    "orderers": [
       { "url" : "grpc://localhost:7050" }
    ],
    "ca": { "url": "http://localhost:7054", 
            "name": "ca.org1.example.com"
    },
    "peers": [
        {
            "requestURL": "grpc://localhost:7051",
            "eventURL": "grpc://localhost:7053"
        }
    ],
    "keyValStore": "${HOME}/.composer-credentials",
    "channel": "composerchannel",
    "mspID": "Org1MSP",
    "timeout": "300"
}

Note I used the fabric-tool script the start the fabric and to generate the profile (hlfv1.json).

docker ps:

570ae25a586e        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.0      "peer node start -..."   30 minutes ago      Up 30 minutes       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com

513431e5d217        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.0.0        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-..."   31 minutes ago      Up 31 minutes       0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.org1.example.com

2e7bf444481d        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:x86_64-1.0.0   "tini -- /docker-e..."   31 minutes ago      Up 31 minutes       4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb

5d5ba67cc602        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.0   "orderer"                31 minutes ago      Up 30 minutes       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the developer tutorial you will see that the id `PeerAdmin` must be used to deploy the network.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html

Comment: If you looked at the doc, it also used admin to deploy, anyway I did try admin and PeerAdmin and they both returned the same error.

Comment: BTW, I am not using Playgroud (I hope this is optional). My test is very simple, I started all docker containers then all I wanted to do now is simply to use CLI to publish a definition, that's all for now. BTW is PeerAdmin  a Fabric member?  I looked at the fabric-server.db,  didn't see such user in the Fabric db.

Comment: For PeerAdmin to work you need to be using the Composer fabric-dev server (ie. following the developer guide).

Comment: Don't know what you meant by fabric-dev server (and I did follow the developer guide).

Comment: ... continues ...


Let me try something very simple, here's what I did :
1) fabric-tool/startFabric.sh
2) composer-rest-server -p profile -n my-network -i admin -s adminpw -N never


.....surprisingly this also generated the same error message!  
( 'profile' is generated by farbric-tool/createComposerProfile.sh...)

...so any idea?

Comment: createComposerProfile.sh creates a profile called `hlfv1` -- so it seems like you are not following the developer guide. Step 2.3 in the Installation instructions here: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html so your -p argument to composer-rest-server should be -p hlfv1

Comment: createComposerProfile.sh will create the connection profile `hlfv1` and will also put the crypto material for an identity that has admin authority to the peer/channel into your KeyValStore defined by the connection profile and it get's labelled as `PeerAdmin`. You must use this id to deploy a business network using the composer network deploy command you cannot use 'admin' to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed.

The confusion was providing the connectionProfileName, the -p option, based on reading the document, I thought I have to provide a file with connection information (even thought the provided profile information contain all necessary information), I didn't know it was actually picking up the profile file from ~/.composer-connection-profiles folder based on the name provided in the -p option.